# Is a MagLoop antenna better than my 50ft end fed di-pole for 20-80 meters?

Tags: antenna, dipole, magnetic-loop

I'm restricted to putting antennas in my attic which is 50 feet long and peaks at about 8 feet. I'm currently using the Nelson UJM-150-50 end-fed dipole 80-10 meter antenna. The attic is about 25 feet above the ground. Would the MFJ (or other) magnetic loop antenna be better? Is there a better option?

Comment: "better" how? Smaller? Lower loss? Higher directivity? Lower takeoff angle? Higher front-to-back ratio? Cheaper? To get a meaningful answer, you'll have to specify at least a little bit about what you want the antenna to do.

Comment: Hi Irv, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2):

Both an end-fed and a small loop antenna might couple into the house wiring on transmit.  You might be able to orient a mag loop to minimize RF noise pickup from the house environment on receive.

As an alternative, I might consider testing a balanced fan dipole for Tx.  For a receive antenna, another possibility might be a large loop around the entire attic, if the EMI/RFI pickup isn’t too bad.